# US citizen incorporating a company where he won't work and hiring an H1B as the CEO

Tags: corporate-law, visa

Can a US citizen incorporate a company where he won't work and hire an H1B visa holder as the CEO?

Comment: Small companies generally find it impractical to sponsor H1Bs. On top of that, Trump suspended the program, I believe.

Comment: A person in H-1B status may only work for the sponsor company.  You won't be able to hire someone who works for another company without transferring the sponsorship.

Answer (score 1):

1. A US citizen may incorporate any company.
   There has never been a need to work in a company you own.
2. An H1B has lower requirements than other visas. So that shouldn't be the problem.
   But it is company-specific and limited.
   So, only one can give you an reliable answer, the USCIS Service Center.
3. As far as I know the H1B visas for 2021 are gone already. Normally, you only have one week until they are all issued.